# Running Mobile Phone Tools on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, mobile-phone

I'm trying to run [mobile phone tools](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Network_and_Internet/3D_and_Graphical_Chat_Tools/Mobile_Phone_Tools_v3.html) on Ubuntu 10.04. I'm doing this so that I can transfer files between my desktop and phone via data cable. The software installs OK, but when I try to run it using the command "wine mPhonetools.exe", the program throws an error and does not start. The error is

err:module:attach_process_dlls "ModExch.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\Program Files\mobile PhoneTools\mPhonetools.exe" failed, status c0000142

Any ideas on what's wrong? Could this be because wine does not have usb support?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wine's Compatibility Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3201) this programm is known not to work.

An alternative to using wine would be to use virtualization (with Virtualbox or VMWare for example).

Habe you tried if your phone is natively supported by Ubuntu? Many phones are recognized likte a thumbdrive.

Comment: I don't have windows, so virtualization is not possible. I don't think my phone is natively supported. It is not detected when plugged in. Thanks anyway. My phone is Samsung SGH-D780 in case someone has previous experience with it.